# Create a 3d shape (non GUI) with a start and end point

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know the traditional way in Unity to position a shape is to give it a center point, then scale and rotate as needed. However, I'd like for the following:

The player can click once to "start" a shape (basically a line, but I could use a cube or whatever) and then click a second time to "end" the shape, completing it and bringing it into existence in the game space. How could this be done?

Comment: You will need to provide more specific information to your question. Do you mean you will click once to initiate the shape and as you drag out from that origin it scales and rotates the shape accordingly? Then click again to keep that exact shape?

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean